# Customising Finder sidebar icons

Tags: macos, finder

I'm trying to figure out how to customise some of my folders' sidebar icons that are using custom ICNS icons via "Get Info". They're basic "Documents", "Downloads", etc. folders that I've replaced with my own on a secondary drive.

Currently running El Capitan 10.11.6.

An option that doesn't require an external app would be ideal. Can Dropbox's method be replicated? Thanks!

Comment: Please include the Mac OS X version number you're running on your Mac.

Comment: @IconDaemon They've updated it now.

Comment: @Peanut Hmm well, that's five years old, and I mentioned that I'd rather not use an app such as CandyBar and that the "Get Info" method doesn't affect the sidebar icons.

Comment: @MarioParra Here is another related post: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/182180/154794

Comment: Per the link that Peanut provided, Dropbox uses an API provided to software developers for the purpose of changing the icon in the sidebar for a given folder. You'd have to write a Mac application to replicate Dropbox's functionality.